# The indentation in Python code appears to be incorrect but the code runs

Tags: python, indentation

**There is no IndentationError or TabError nor am I asking how to fix any such error. The program runs as intended.**

I received some Python code to maintain. How can this possibly work and why it crashes with unindent error only if I modify the internals of the inner for loop?

```
        for m in range(len(Model)):
        if param==1:
            m=m-1

            parFlag = 0
            for s in range(len(PSets)):
                if Parameter.lower() in self._Sets._P_ModelVars[Model[m]][PSets[s]]:
                    parFlag = 1
```

It looks even stranger now when I am entering it here:

[image]

I think it can have something to do with tabs, but I don't know much about them except I try to avoid them wherever possible.

Comment: Did you mix leading spaces and tabs?

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know and I am trying to understand it. It seems like the parts with strange indentation were written by a different developer with also poorer style in choosing variable names and other stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, the code is mixing tabs and spaces:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint('''\
...                     for m in range(len(Model)):
...                 if param==1:
...                     m=m-1
... 
...                 parFlag = 0
...                 for s in range(len(PSets)):
...                     if Parameter.lower() in self._Sets._P_ModelVars[Model[m]][PSets[s]]:
...                         parFlag = 1
... '''.splitlines())
['    \t\tfor m in range(len(Model)):',
 '\t\t    if param==1:',
 '\t\t    \tm=m-1',
 '',
 '        \t    parFlag = 0',
 '        \t    for s in range(len(PSets)):',
 '\t                if Parameter.lower() in self._Sets._P_ModelVars[Model[m]][PSets[s]]:',
 '\t                    parFlag = 1']
```

Note all the mix of `\t` and  characters at the start of each line.

A good text editor will let you replace the tabs with spaces, and also let you set what style should be used when creating new indentations. The [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends you stick with only spaces.

You can detect where spaces and tabs are mixed by running the code with the `-tt` command line switch:

```
python -tt yourscript.py
```

Comment: Finally I used regex search and replace in `kate`. I only had to find out that it \t stands for 8 characters.